# Rails: Remove missing translation errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, rails-i18n

I am using internationalization for **english (en)** and **french (fr)**, I have used en.yml for limited use and most of the translations I am writing in fr.yml.

With **locale as fr** everything works good, but with **en it shows me error** as missing translation span.

For eg if I have got something like

```
<%= text_field_tag( "search", params[:search], :placeholder=>t("Search"), :class=>"search_input") %>
```

and i get output for en is:

```
<input class="search_input" id="search" name="search" placeholder="<span class=" translation_missing"="" title="translation missing: en.Search">
```

What I want is that it should **turn off translation errors for english**, since english is my default language, but for some cases I've used en.yml.

Or if this is not possible then whole error message should be removed.

Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The implementation of HTML missing translation errors has been changed in Rails 4.1. Now instead of I18n library it is handled on the view helper layer. Namely, in "translate" helper method (see action_view/helpers/translation_helper.rb).

A clean way to do this now is to override the helper method and handle the exception yourself.

```
# app/helpers/i18n_helper.rb

module I18nHelper
  def translate(key, options={})
    super(key, options.merge(raise: true))
  rescue I18n::MissingTranslationData
    key
  end
  alias :t :translate
end
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm not quite able to get this to work, though :-/ I put this in `config/initializers/i18n.rb`, and the files get loaded correctly, but I still get the `<span>` tags... Using `I18n.method(:t).source_location` I ended up in `i18n-0.6.9/lib/i18n.rb`, which defined the module `I18n`, no trace of a `I18nHelper` module in this directory? (Changing the module to `I18n` did not make it work)... Did I use it wrong? Am I missing a step?

Comment: This is a regular helper module which should go into app/helpers. I've edited the post to clarify that.

Comment: Thank you, that wasn't too obvious for a rails newcomer. ;)

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for thanks for this solution. Instead of just returning the `key` I use `scope_key_by_partial(key)`, then you get the full path to the key.

Comment: @MarkusGraf the [Lazy Lookup](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#lazy-lookup) is supposed to do this already

Answer (score 15):

At first sight the [Rails I18n guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html) seem pretty good, and cover this pretty well (e.g. an example to declare a custom exception handler).

But according to [this ticket](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/13429) it does not work in rails since 4.0.2 and up (but should be fixed in latest rails 4.1 release).

Apparently the behaviour has changed and the exception handler is ignored now.

Available options:

- explicitly add option `raise: true`, which will force the exceptionhandler to be used. E.g. `t('.missing', raise: true)`.
- in the newest rails 4.1 release you can set the default behaviour back to raising an exception: `config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true` (see [merge ticket](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/13832) for more info)
- or alternatively, explicitly add a default option: `t('.missing', default: 'use this instead')`

Comment: Thanks. Changing all a whole bunch of `t()` just to aid me with development is not feasible; Setting the exception handler seems to work, but no exceptions seem to be intercepted at all (see: http://pastebin.com/G8qyXtsz) ... `I18n::MissingTranslation::Base::to_exception` is still being called ... :-/

Comment: Addendum: it *does* work as expected from `rails c`, but *not* from a HAML template...?

Comment: Did you try setting the mentioned configuration flag? Indeed, in views the exception is no longer raised, unless you set the config flag, or explicitly give the option `raise => true`.

Comment: Yeah, I set the config, and it raised the exceptions... I managed to get this working [with a different solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23244305/660921) by the way ...

Comment: So if the exceptions were raised: why did you choose the other solution?

Comment: I wasn't able to catch the exception and just print a message (ie. the key)

Answer (score 6):

I18n library uses *exception handler* to decide what to do with missing translations.
By default it returns "translation missing" message:

```
# i18n/exceptions.rb
class I18n::ExceptionHandler
  include Module.new {
    def call(exception, locale, key, options)
      if exception.is_a?(MissingTranslation)
        # Rails sets :rescue_format to :html in views
        # so that you will get span tag instead of just text message
        options[:rescue_format] == :html ? exception.html_message : exception.message
      elsif exception.is_a?(Exception)
        raise exception
      else
        throw :exception, exception
      end
    end
  }
end
```

You can extend the exception handler to just return translation key when the translation is missing:

```
# config/initializers/i18n.rb
module UseKeyForMissing
  def call(exception, locale, key, options)
    if exception.is_a?(I18n::MissingTranslation)
      key
    else
      super
    end
  end
end

I18n.exception_handler.extend UseKeyForMissing
```

Then assuming you have only french translations:

```
I18n.t("Search", :locale => :fr) #=> "Rechercher"
I18n.t("Search", :locale => :en) #=> "Search"
```

Comment: i tried using it, but didn't work for me, I have got the solution, will be posting it soon. Thanks

Comment: I don't understand some object expect error was coming. I can't figure it out

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to fill in translations for English, a possible solution here would be to have your translations fallback to French.

You can achieve this by adding the following code to an initializer (eg. `config/initalizers/i18n.rb`) :

```
require "i18n/backend/fallbacks" 
I18n::Backend::Simple.send(:include, I18n::Backend::Fallbacks)
```

If French is set up as your default locale, this should "Just Work".

Otherwise you may need to add a custom fallback rule to the initializer :

```
I18n.fallbacks.map(:en => :fr)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<%= text_field_tag( "search", params[:search], :placeholder=>t(:search), :class=>"search_input") %>
```

and in your en.yml file write

```
search: 'Search'
```

Comment: you mean it will not give translation error, i want to write normal english in template, translation i want only for other languages

Comment: t("Search") transaltion is not their in your en.yml file so that add this like - search: 'Search' and call like t(:search)

Comment: read the ques first, what you are telling me to do is same as adding translation to en.yml, i don't want that

Comment: have you got some solution for this

Answer (score 1):

Given below code is to remove missing translation for english, we monkey patch MissingTranslation module of I18n, by putting it in initializers.

```
DEFAULT_TEMPLATE_LANG = 'en'        
# Removing missing translation errors for english
module I18n
  class MissingTranslation
    def html_message
      if DEFAULT_TEMPLATE_LANG == keys[0].to_s
        keys[1].to_s
      else
        "missing translation: #{keys.join('.')}"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

In Rails 4.1, I wasn't able to get this to work with the I18n exception handler (there are some bugs, apparently, see [nathanvda's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23241864/660921).
Eventually I just overwrote the `message` function by adding this to `config/initializers/i18n.rb`

```
module I18n
  class MissingTranslation
    module Base
      def message
        keys[1..-1].join('.')
      end
    end
  end
end
```