# Rails: i18n, variable gets printed if translation is not there

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, rails-i18n

I am facing a weird problem. In my rails 3 app I am supporting internationalization with english and french. Here in my template I wrote something like this

```
<%= t "Hi %{person}!", :person => "Simpson" %>
```

When I set locale as french everything works fine, since it has got translation for this but when I set locale as english then it gives output as

```
Hi %{person}!
```

in my browser. When I add translation to en.yml, it works fine. I don't understand why there is need to add translation in en.yml for this. Moreover  I don't want this to happen, is there any work around for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument givent to the `t` method should be a key, so your view should have something like this :

```
<%= t :greetings, :person => "Simpson" %>
```

Your `config/locales/en.yml` would look like this :

```
en:
  greetings: Hi %{person}
```

and your `config/locales/fr.yml` something like this :

```
fr:
  greetings: Bonjour %{person}
```

Comment: I don't want any translation in en.yml, what should be done in that case. In your solution however I am adding translation.

Comment: Well either the same response as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12914019/rails-remove-missing-translation-errors/12930993#comment17524467_12930993 applies or you can just not I18n, like this : <%= "Hi #{person}" %>