# RAILS: How to eliminate `translation missing` from some I18n.t in production (I18n.t fallback enabled)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, internationalization

In my Rails 4.2 app, all modules are developed with I18n.t(). Here is an example of the index.html.erb:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
  <thead>    
    <tr>
      <th><%= t('Create Date') %></th>
      <th><%= t(@for_which.sub('_', ' ').titleize) %></th>
      <th><%= t('Brief Note') %></th>
      <th><%= t('Ranking Index') %></th>
      <th><%= t('Active') %></th>
      <th><%= t('Entered By') %></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
     </thead>
       <tbody>
```

In `local.rb` under `initializers`, local is set to `en`:

```
I18n.enforce_available_locales = false
I18n.default_locale = 'en' if Rails.env.production? || Rails.env.development?
I18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('config', 'locales', '**', '*.{rb,yml}')]
```

But I still see error of `translation missing` from some of the `I18n.t` in both production and development, such as tab and index title as below:
[image]

How do I get rid of error of `translation missing`?

UPDATE: The error `translation missing` shows up in `production` even with the following `I18n.t` fallback in `environment/production.rb`:

```
 # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true
```

UPDATE:
Added CSS:

```
//hide all "translation missing" warnings:
body.production span.translation_missing {
  display: none;
}
```

But words on tab, buttons, and table header disappear:
[image]

Here is portion of html source showing for one of the tab `Employee Infos`:

```
            <li class="dropdown">
        <a id="dropdownuser" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" ><span class="glyphicons glyphicons-yen text-danger"></span> <span class="translation_missing" title="translation missing: en.Employee Info">Employee Info</span> <b class="caret" id="caret_medium"></b></a>
              <ul id="banktransaction" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">

                <li><a href="/tt/view_handler?index=1&amp;url=/tt/tsheet/employee_infos"><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-list'></i> translation missing: en.List</a></li>
                <li></li>
                <li><a href="/tt/view_handler?index=1&amp;url=/tt/tsheet/employee_infos/search"><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt'></i> translation missing: en.Search</a></li>                
              </ul>
            </li>
```

Comment: See if this can resolve your problem.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12914019/rails-remove-missing-translation-errors

Comment: ahhhh add `Customers` key under `en.yaml` ??

Comment: @user938363 I deleted my answer. The 1st solution should of course be to **add the translations to the `en` dictionary file**, just as @niceman suggests. I somehow supposed that you cannot do that and that you need to hide the rest of the warnings, but after rereading your question I see you don't state anything like that anywhere. If this is really the case, update the question and I'll repost a thoroughly updated answer how to amend the preferred rails behavior. Sorry for this misunderstanding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in your **#config/application.rb** file you can do something like this

```
Rails.application.configure do |config|
  config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = false
end
```

you can get more [here](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/foolproof-i18n-setup-in-rails)

I hope that this is able to help you :)

Comment: `MZaragoza`, I can only put it in `/environment/development.rb or production.rb`.It does not work in `application.rb`. Also it still showing the translation missing error. Even in production. Odd.

Comment: This won't do any change as this is the [default](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-2-stable/actionview/lib/action_view/base.rb#L154) in Rails 4.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why, but I just restarted my server and boom! It worked.

You can try restarting your server too :)

Answer (score 0):

Use     'Faker::Job' instead of 'Name.title '

```
Faker::Job
Faker::Job.title #=> "Lead Accounting Associate"

Faker::Job.field #=> "Manufacturing"

Faker::Job.seniority #=> "Lead"

Faker::Job.position #=> "Supervisor"

Faker::Job.key_skill #=> "Teamwork"

Faker::Job.employment_type #=> "Full-time"

Faker::Job.education_level #=> "Bachelor"
```

It works for me :)

Comment: How does this answer the question? Please add a description to your answer.